# Default GW IP address shared with management interface IP: any securirty implications?

Tags: network, firewalls, vlans

Building out separate VLAN for management interfaces.
The proposition is to use Default GW IP address as a management interface for network device.
Any security concerns?

Comment: Default GW IP address of what as the management interface IP of what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, the accepted best practice for management interfaces is to segregate them into their own VLAN and apply filtering so that only certain whitelisted (*read* **jump boxes**) are authorized to communicate with devices via the management interface.

The security concern is that many times management interfaces have:

- Known vulnerabilities (e.g., HP SMH *which seems to have a new one every week*)
- Weak or default passwords
- Few controls to prevent bruteforce attacks (e.g., fail2ban, lockout windows, etc)
- Devastating impact availability if compromised.